# How to set SOAP Envelope Header in Spring Integration with data from int-http:inbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-ws, spring-integration-http

I tried to build a simple spring integration project where I get a REST request and  convert it to a SOAP request. Something like:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="rest-inbound-gateway" request-channel="restRequestChannel"
    reply-channel="restOutputChannel" supported-methods="POST"
    path="/somepath" request-payload-type="com.something.RequestObject">
        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:transformer ref="RestToSoapTransformer" method="transform"
                 input-channel="restRequestChannel" output-channel="transformedChannel"/>

<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="marshallingGateway"
    request-channel="transformedChannel" reply-channel="restOutputChannel"
    uri="http://localhost:8088/mockSoapBinding" marshaller="marshaller"
    message-sender="messageSender"
    unmarshaller="marshaller" >
</int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

But some informations which are in the REST request need to put to the SAOP envelope header and not the envelope body. Eg.

REST Request:

```
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar"
}
```

And SOAP Request sould be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <foo>foo</foo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
         <bar>bar</bar>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I do that? The transformer only create the soap body, and the in an interceptor or header mapper I don't have the original request anymore. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers).

> **WS Message Headers**
>
> The Spring Integration WebService Gateways will map the SOAP Action header automatically. It will be copied by default to and from Spring Integration MessageHeaders using the DefaultSoapHeaderMapper.
>
> Of course, you can pass in your own implementation of SOAP specific header mappers, as the gateways have respective properties to support that.
>
> Any user-defined SOAP headers will NOT be copied to or from a SOAP Message, unless explicitly specified by the requestHeaderNames and/or replyHeaderNames properties of the DefaultSoapHeaderMapper.
>
> ...

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question equivocally. I need to set SOAP envelope header and not soap action header. I enlarged the question.

Comment: That's exactly what the documentation describes `Any user-defined SOAP headers will NOT be copied to or from a SOAP Message, unless explicitly specified by the requestHeaderNames and/or replyHeaderNames properties of the DefaultSoapHeaderMapper.`. Add a `<header-enricher/>` before the gateway to add the headers, then configure the mapper to map them via the`requestHeaderNames` property.

Comment: Thanks! Now if I'm return a String in my `<header-enricher/>` its in the header like `<SOAP-ENV:Header foo="bar"/>. Is there a way to put it under the header element in a separate tag? If I'm returning an object or a JAXBElement, it is not appear in the header at all.

Comment: See [the documentation I pointed you to](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers). You can use a `StringSource` as the header value - scroll down to the bottom of that section.